# Lumia 735 with Windows 10 Mobile Gmail send button disabled

Tags: windows-10-mobile, email, gmail, nokia-lumia-735

I have a Lumia 735 with Windows 10 Mobile installed.
Ever since a few days ago, I can't send replies for emails from my Google account.
If I create a new mail, the send button is enabled, but if I try to reply to an email, only the `attach` button is active, whereas `delete` and `send` are inactive. The strange part is that if I use another email accounts, reply is working fine.

**Update:** soft-reset does not solve the problem.

**Update 2:** there's a thread about this problem on [Windows Central forum](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile-insider-preview/423972-cant-reply-forward-emails-outlook-send-button-greyed-out-build-242-a.html), if I get any solution I'll post it.

Here's a screenshot about the problem:
[image: send button is disabled]

Device information:

```
Version: 1511
OS build: 10.0.10586.218
Firmware revision number: 02177.00000.15184.36003
Hardware revision number: 3.0.0.0
```